# How can I debug a MySQL error "MySQL shutdown unexpectedly" in XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am trying to run the MySQL server through XAMPP for connection with php and every time, I try to do so, this error is being shown. I have tried everything from reinstalling to changing port address but this still didn't work. How can I solve this error?

Error

```
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
12:15:26  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
12:15:26  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
12:15:26  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
12:15:26  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
12:15:26  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
12:15:26  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums\
```

Error log :

```
2020-06-06 12:13:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-06-06 12:13:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-06-06 12:13:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-06-06 12:13:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\XamppReintalled\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-06-06 12:13:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\XamppReintalled\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-06-06 12:13:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.15 started; log sequence number 1804856; transaction id 209
2020-06-06 12:13:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\XamppReintalled\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-06-06 12:13:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200606 12:13:59
2020-06-06 12:13:59 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-06-06 12:13:59 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-06-06 12:13:59 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2020-06-06 12:13:59 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3308 ?
2020-06-06 12:13:59 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: show the content of the log

Comment: I am not able to add full error log here as it is very long. I have added a part of it in the question

Comment: Looks like port binding of your my.cnf is not ok. Bind to 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. If that is not working use 0.0.0.0.

Comment: I just tried that, it's still not working

Comment: try changing your port number? see the `[ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3308 ?`

Comment: try restarting your machine too after each reinstall to kill all the service

Comment: Have a look in your Task Manager in Windows - you are running another copy of MySQL. At a guess you have XAMPP installed twice in some fashion. Have a look for another MySQL process.

Comment: Yaa, there is already a service running named as mysqld. Can I somehow use external mysql service with php or do I need to use the one provided with xampp. If so, how?

Comment: You can STOP the service to avoid blocking your attempt to use current MySQL.